# Appcelerator Studio vs Titanium Studio

Tags: eclipse, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I expected that these would be the same thing, but after looking around the Appcelerator website, it seems that they may actually be two separate IDEs.

Currently on the site (http://www.appcelerator.com/), under the Products menu item are links to Appcelerator Platform and Titanium. The latter is obviously the IDE and the former is just the name of the complete package that includes the dashboard, analytics, marketplace and all that other stuff. It is not an actual piece of software.

Note also that only the Titanium page has breadcrumbs showing the other products.

However, after Googling "appcelerator studio", the second result was a link to this page: http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/appcelerator-studio/

At first I thought it was a disabled link that was cached in Google's index, as I couldn't find any internal link on the site to this page, but then I read the following line:

> Appcelerator Studio IDE – a powerful Eclipse-based IDE, based on
>   Titanium Studio IDE

So I was confused; is Appcelerator Studio a new IDE that they haven't made public yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Its the enterprise edition of their platform.

It includes:

> Built-in profiler, code analyzer, and LiveView editor to accelerate prototyping and development and measure code quality.

All features not available in the community edition.

Comment: Ah I see it now, for only $1000/month. Thanks.

Comment: also automated testing tools, better analytics and crash reporting

Comment: therefore if you use "Titanium Studio" is for free?

Comment: yes it is free, I have not paid for anything the past three years

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator Studio extends the features of Titanium Studio, and  it help you to manage your mobile project through its entire lifecycle and develop your application more easily.

It provides the following additional features.

1. Dashboard Analytics
2. Automated testing
3. Performance Monitoring
4. Code Profiling
5. App Designer
6. Hyperloop
7. Live View
8. Crash reporting services

and, many more...

If somebody starting new, I would suggest them to use Appcelerator Studio.